# Is it possible to get a shift character in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, keyboard, character, shift

Is it possible to get a shift character in Java or JavaFX?

For example, if I have the char `'1'` and I want the shift character on a qwertz layout. I get the `'!'`.

Because I have a JavaFX `KeyEvent` and I want the character which is pressed. But the `KeyEvent` didn't get me shift character for `1`. Only for letters.

Is this possible without JNI or is there a workaround for example with a `TextField` and events?

Or should I use a own `Map`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should listen for [`KEY_TYPED`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#KEY_TYPED) events and query [`KeyEvent#getCharacter()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#getCharacter()). If the user types <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> then `#getCharacter()` will return `"!"`, at least on a typical US QWERTY keyboard.

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Text text = new Text();
    primaryStage.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, event -> {
      event.consume();
      text.setText(text.getText() + event.getCharacter());
    });
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(text), 500, 300));
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

***Note:** The above is not an exhaustive implementation. For instance, typing <kbd>Backspace</kbd> won't delete a character but will instead add an "unknown character" because the `\b` character has no representation.*

Comment: Thx, I tested released and pressed event but not the typed event xD
It seems, that this works for me

Comment: Yes, I already realized that there is a "unknown character". I wrote a small filter for these cases:
`@FXML
void consolKeyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
  String text = event.getCharacter();
  if(text.length() > 0) {
   char c = text.charAt(0);
   
   switch(c) {
    case '\b':
    case '\n':
    case '\r':
    case '\f':
    return;
   }
   
   if(event.isControlDown() && !event.isAltDown()) return;
   addChar(c);
  }
}` (I don't know how use multiline in comment)